Can we have single KeyCloak page where multiple saml based applications appears
I’ve successfully integrated with AWS IAM and GitLab.
I was using Okta earlier and there when we logon multiple applications those are integrated with used to appears, can we have the same in KeyCloak ?
Many Thanks
For now, I have 2 separate url’s one for AWS and second for Gitlab.
I don’t want to use 2 separate url’s instead when I logon KeyCloak I should see the option to choose which client or application I need to access.
is that possible ? please guide.

do I understand correctly, you want a IDP Initiated session displayed in keycloak UI?

Hm Yes, as of now I have integrated keycloak with AWS and GitLab, but for accessing them I have 2 separate url's
for example: https://keycloak.services.-np.securitysvcs.com/realms/lmre/protocol/saml/clients/aws-client
&
ttps://keycloak.services.-np.securitysvcs.com/realms/lmre/protocol/saml/clients/gitlab-client
what I want is just a single url ttps://keycloak.services.-np.securitysvcs.com/realms/lmre/protocol/saml
& once I logon I should get option to access either AWS or GitLab, is it possible ?
like we have in okta
